# Unable to install DDR2 RAM in old desktop

Tags: memory, ddr2

I am attempting to install more memory in a Dell Vostro 200 running 64-bit Windows 8.1. It currently has two 1GB DDR2 800MHz Corsair sticks. I have two more sticks of virtually identical RAM which prevent the computer from booting when installed in conjunction with the original sticks as well as when installed alone. The only difference between the two sets of RAM is the version number. The original sticks are labeled version 7.6, whereas the new RAM is labeled version 5.2. Would the difference in version numbers account for the incompatibility or am I missing something here?

Edit: The Dell motherboard model number is 0cu409. [This photo](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOdWmHx-p_sImOIYjLwC-5v8XbEEc3xlDsTWFea6PzoutlJ2KfRsAe4WFAGppntVQ?key=azZwcXIyZUE1ZXFzY3ZtbWIxcTBuNURoTUpvczFn) shows the two new RAM sticks at top and one of the older RAM sticks at the bottom.

Comment: It is possible that you are using incompatible RAM with that motherboard. To verify this, you will need to refer to your motherboard's documentation and check out the supported Memory for that board. It is unlikely that a difference in revision numbers would hinder your PC from booting.

Also, it is possible that those modules are DOA. We might be able to help a little bit better if you can provide us the model # of your motherboard and the RAM you are currently using, as well as the RAM you are trying to install.

Comment: "Would the difference in version numbers account for the incompatibility or am I missing something here?" - No;  Having upgraded a Dell Vostro 200 myself in the last week, can you submit a picture of the current memory, and the new memory side-by-side?   We also need exact and percise information off the labels, is one perhaps ECC and the other non-ECC memory?  Provide us exact model and part-numbers.

Comment: You should try putting the older RAM in the slots currently occupied. First, try this by itself (you may need to verify it in the BIOS). Then add the newer RAM in the unused slots. If the later revision is faster in any of its timings, then this will run all the RAM at the older timings, which are derived from whatever memory is in the first slot.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what goes wrong when you try to boot the computer? Does it beep? Do you get a display? Does it try to load the OS? Your problem description is very vague.

Comment: The computer beeps and the screen remains black when the new RAM is installed. It fails to boot at all. According to CPU-Z the motherboard model number is 0cu409. The link below is a photo of the new and old RAM. The top two are the new RAM sticks, the bottom is one of the old functional RAM sticks. [link](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOdWmHx-p_sImOIYjLwC-5v8XbEEc3xlDsTWFea6PzoutlJ2KfRsAe4WFAGppntVQ?key=azZwcXIyZUE1ZXFzY3ZtbWIxcTBuNURoTUpvczFn)

Answer (score 0):

Difference in versions wont matter as if parameters : Frequency, Voltage and Timing are the same, then you should be ok.
What it colud be is that your new ram MAY BE! faulty

Try testing the non-working sticks in another DDR2 pc, maybe from family, friends..etc.
Dont worry about motherboard compatibility, if its DDR2 it will work, maybe just for booting.What you need is, the bios to detect the ram